# how to stop asp.net encrypting the querystring

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have a requirement where I have to pass some values into the next page via querystring.
This querystring is coming from third party and they need to have it on the otherpage for some analysis.

I just do a response.redirect and add the querystring that i recieve from them to the other page. My problem is that the .net environment is encoding/encrypting some of the special characters used by them which I dont want as it does not bring back the correct values in the new page.

Example:

passed url :

```
abcd.efgh=testing|value1=rtedf%20value2%202010-04-07%207pm|value3=aaaa
```

This gets changed to

```
abcd.efgh=testing|value1%3drtedf+value2+2010-04-07+7pm|value3%3daaaa
```

It looks like "=" becomes "%3d" and "%20" a space becomes "+"

How can I stop the encoding of url and pass it in its original form.

Comment: they are the same in the sense that the URLs will do the same thing...
I.e. the thing you want to pass as a URL is an illigal URL, and therefore it gets converted to the form you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your querystrings are being [URL encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). This is standard behaviour due to how URLs should be formatted. What you need to do on the receiving page is to use [UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx) in order to get back to your original string.

Comment: My main problem is my whole app never used the querystrings but the new third party which is analyzing our internet traffic is passing some the querystring which is being transferred to my .net app but they have asked us to put someof their javascripts in our code which does the parsing of the url querystrings to get the value they want. Now its their javascript that needs to take care of this encoding is it not. I dont think I can do anything from my end for that. Just want to make sure if I am thinking in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, once you've sent them the URL, they'll have to decode it. It's possible to decode in Javascript using decodeURIComponent (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeURIComponent.asp).

Answer (score 1):

This is not called encryption, it is **url-encoding** and is an HTTP requirement.

You cannot stop ASP.NET and you should really not try stopping it!